# Order the number of multiple occurrences

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by

Let's say I have the following data:

```
2
2
2
3
3
3
4
4
5
5
```

I'd like to output a table that calculates how often there are duplicates and order it by the number of duplicates.

In the example, there are two times data with 3 duplicates and two times data with 2 duplicates, so the output would be:

```
2    3
2    2
```

Is there an easy way to do this in SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a histogram-of-histograms query.  You just need two aggregations:

```
select cnt, count(*)
from (select col, count(*) as cnt
      from t
      group by col
     ) t
group by cnt;
```

Comment: Add `ORDER BY count(*) DESC` and you're all set.

Answer (score 0):

Use inner query to get the repetition of each data point and then use outer query to GROUP BY those repetition to get how many times these repetition occur.

```
SELECT i.repetition, COUNT(*) as times
FROM (SELECT column_name, COUNT(*) as repetition
        FROM TABLE_NAME
      GROUP BY column_name) as i
GROUP BY i.repetition
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```